# How to read parquet files with log structured data using parquet-mr

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

In our storage layer, we add json documents and store them in parquet format in log structured fashion (via parquet-cpp and our implementation of dremel paper) for better write efficiency. This means there can be multiple row entries for a single documentID (documentID is one of the column attributes) in two or more parquet files. documentID is supposed to be the unique/primary key. I intend to read these parquet files via parquet-hive storage handler as well as spark-sql. My question is, are there known ways of handling log structured parquet data? Or do i need to modify parquet-mr implementation to do the same.